# How to use COUNTIFS with multiple conditions and columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, countif

I am trying to count the number of values using COUNTIFS based on multiple conditions and multiple columns in Excel. Here is an example of what I am trying below:

```
ColumnA        ColumnB
16             12.4
-              2
15             -
8              -
-              25
-              12
20             23
15             19
12.5           10
```

The criteria that I am trying to check for is where ColumnA is greater than 12.5 and also to check where each of the values in ColumnB is greater than the corresponding value in the same row compared to ColumnA. So in this sample data above, the count should be 2 because only two rows in ColumnA have a value greater than 12.5 and also where the corresponding ColumnB value is greater than the value in ColumnA.

I've tried this but it's giving me a 0 count,

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A9, ">12.5", B1:B9, ">A1:A9")
```

Comment: `=SUM((A1:A9>12.5)*(B1:B9>A1:A9))`

Comment: @JvdV it will work if those "-" are actually blanks. If not, for example "-">12.5 = TRUE

Comment: `=SUM(MAP(A1:A9,B1:B9,LAMBDA(x,y,COUNTIFS(x,">12.5",y,">"&x))))` using `COUNTIFS()` bt within `MAP()` & `LAMBDA()`

Comment: @user11222393, I assumed blanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using SUMPRODUCT and [double unay operators](https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary):

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A9>12.5)*--(B1:B9>A1:A9)*--(ISNUMBER(B1:B9)))
```

Comment: Actually the double unay operators are not required if you multiply the array. That converts the boolean to numeric already

Answer (score 2):

Showing for the sake of using `COUNTIFS()` with `MAP()` but it can be resolved using `SUMPRODUCT()` as shown above by **[Foxfire And Burns And Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9199828/foxfire-and-burns-and-burns)** Sir

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B11`

```
=SUM(MAP(A1:A9,B1:B9,LAMBDA(x,y,COUNTIFS(x,">12.5",y,">"&x))))
```

---

It basically returns an array of `1` & `0`s and hence need to wrap within `SUM()`:

[image]

---

```
=MAP(A1:A9,B1:B9,LAMBDA(x,y,COUNTIFS(x,">12.5",y,">"&x)))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Or like this:

[image]

```
IF(AND(A2>12.5,A2<B2,B2<>"-"),1,0)
```

This may be a more stable version:

```
IF(AND(A2>12.5,A2<B2,ISNUMBER(B2)),1,0)
```